# keep words after keyword in string R

Tags: r, regex, text-mining

**Problem:** I am working with a tokenizer for text mining and would like to limit the length of strings in my input data. The following code keeps the 
entire string if the word is included.

```
    #create data frame with data 
    dd <- data.frame(
    text = c("hello how are you doing thank 
              you for helping me with this 
              problem","junk","junk"), stringsAsFactors = F)

   #keep string that only include term "how"
   dd <- filter(dd, grepl('how', text))
```

**Question:** How can I modify the code to just keep N words after the key words.

e.g.

if N =1 then dd would include: how are

if N =2 then dd would include: how are you

if N =3 then dd would include: how are you doing

**...**

I need code that would work if I also included additional words in the keep:

```
   #keep string that only include terms "how" and "with"
   dd <- filter(dd, grepl('how|with', text))
```

Comment: Not really a regex guru but this may help you : https://regex101.com/r/95g7yT/1

Comment: What do you expect to see as a result If you specify two terms, `"how"` and `"with"` and N = 3 for example? Also, what if the distance between the two terms is less then 3 words, like if we'd picked `"hello"` and `"are"`?

Comment: 1 - With two terms "how" OR "with"  and N=3 I would like to generate: "how are you doing with this problem". The results for the second term "with" would only keep words until the end of the string. 2 - If the terms were "hello" and "are", I would like to keep: "hello how are you doing thank" if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible approach wih tidy text mining packages.:
(so check dependencies...-

```
library(tidytext) # install.packages("tidytext")
library(tidyr)    # install.packages("tidyr")
library(dplyr)    # install.packages("dplyr")

dd <- data.frame(
  text = c("hello how are you doing thank 
              you for helping me with this 
              problem","junk","junk"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I mention as `scope` your parameter about words horizon; easy to turn following code into a function:

```
scope=2
dd %>%
  unnest_tokens(ngram, text, token = "ngrams", n = 1+scope) %>% 
  separate(ngram, paste("word",1:(scope+1),sep=""), sep = " ") %>% 
  filter(word1 %in% c("how","me")) 

# A tibble: 2 × 3
  word1 word2 word3
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1   how   are   you
2    me  with  this
```

In case you want to end up with strings, you have to collapse back ngrams, cf for instance this second example:

```
scope=3
dd %>%
unnest_tokens(ngram, text, token = "ngrams", n = 1+scope) %>% 
  separate(ngram, paste("word",1:(scope+1),sep=""), sep = " ") %>% 
  filter(word1 %in% c("how"))  %>% apply(.,1,paste, collapse= " ")

[1] "how are you doing"
```

Regarding your comment:
Now if you want to work chunk (string) per chunk (string), you must explicitely perform this group by processing.
Here is a way for instance:

```
scope=2
subsets <- 
    dd %>% 
    mutate(id=1:length(text)) %>%
    split(., .$id) 

unlist(lapply(subsets, function(dd) {
  dd %>%
  unnest_tokens(ngram, text, token = "ngrams", n = 1+scope) %>% 
  separate(ngram, paste("word",1:(scope+1),sep=""), sep = " ")  %>%
  filter(word1 %in% c("how","problem")) %>%
  apply(.,1,FUN=function(vec) paste(vec[-1],collapse=" "))
}))

           1 
"how are you"
```

Comment: By the way, I recommend the reading of excellent Text Mining with R -- http://tidytextmining.com/

Comment: Thank you @Eric Lecoutre

Comment: If I run scope=2 with c("how","problem")
I receive: 1     "how   are   you";  2 "problem  junk  junk"
Words from the second row and third row in the frame are included. How can the code be modified to treat each string for a row separately?
@Eric Lecoutre

Comment: What is then the expected result for related with the word "problem"? String "problem" alone or nothing as there are no any consecutive words with regards to the scope? Also: are you interested by the option 1 (a vector of words) or option 2 (a string) in my proposal?

Comment: If word = “problem” and scope is greater than 1 then nothing. I am interested in options 2 (a string). Thanks for letting me clarify.

Comment: merci.  that answers my question.